# Linear optimization doesnot work with upper bounds

Tags: optimization, scipy

I am trying to minimize objective function with scipy linprog.It work good under equilibrium condition,but fails if I define upper bounds.I try several things but could not be able to solve the problem.Here is the code:

```
c=[0.9,0.25,0.,1.25,4.5,0]
AUB=[[0.99,0.001,0.043,0,0,0.031],[0,0.001,0.01,0.7,0,0.0185],
[0,0,0,0,0.99,0.0045],[1,1,1,1,1,1]]
AEQ=[[0.99,0.001,0.043,0,0,0.031],[0,0.001,0.001,0.7,0,0.0185],
[0,0,0,0,0.99,0.0045],[1,1,1,1,1,1]]
BUB=[3.2,1.85,0.5,100]
BEQ=[2.9,1.5,0.0,100]
res=linprog(c,A_ub=AUB,b_ub=BUB,A_eq=AEQ,b_eq=BEQ,options={"disp":True})
```

If I change the last line with this code

```
res=linprog(c,A_eq=AEQ,b_eq=BEQ,options={"disp":True})
```

or this one

```
res=linprog(c,A_eq=AEQ,b_eq=BUB,options={"disp":True})
```

I get 3 different values for objective function.But the minumun is the 3rd one.It should give this result for the 1st function,shouldn't it ?

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Why do you think the results are wrong? Just take your working result (eq-only) and check the UB-constraints on it. The solution with eq-only is infeasible when ub's are added!

Comment: Thankyou very much .I will try and return

Comment: I have corrected my mistakes

Comment: Your analysis makes not much sense and the results are 100% correct. Please read some introduction to linear-programming before exploring thos code. (why should the objective of some problem like 1 be lower than another like 3, when there are different equality-constraints?)

Comment: This is a small charge calculation problem in metalurgy by cost minimization,and it is solved easily by excel solver using linear optimization.I am just trying to adapt scipy linear optimization.

Comment: It does not matter. The results are correct and if that's not something you expect, you should check whatever brought you to these values. And if you still claim it to be wrong, then write it up in some formal way (possibly showing some alternative solution with a better objective while being feasible or whatever the problem is) as currently it reads as: i change the constraints and the objective changes too (which is normal for LPs).